# pandas: adding two integer series to create new column in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I used to add two columns in a pandas `DataFrame` using the + operator. This does not seem to work anymore:

```
arr = np.array([[70, 90, 80], [68, 80, 93]])
df = pd.DataFrame(arr,columns= ['c1','c2','c3'])
df.c2 + df.c3
```

This now throws a value error. What am I doing wrong here?

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
> ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: try with bracket notation `df['c2']+df['c3']` or `df['c2'].add(df['c3'])`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The bracket notation also not working . Add function works tho. I am not sure if it’s related pandas version